# Is there a way to read .pbstream file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I need to read .pbstream file. I need to achieve result like [this](https://github.com/meyerjo/cartographer-read-pbstream). I already tried to use script from this repository and I have this error and steel couldn't resolved it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pbstream.reader import PBstream_Reader
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbstream-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/pbstream/reader.py", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartographer.mapping'
```

Is there any package that solves this task or maybe is there any suggestion how to solve this No module named 'cartographer.mapping' problem. Appreciate any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409130/is-there-a-way-to-read-.pbstream-file?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may look in this code

http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/cartographer_ros/html/pbstream__to__ros__map__main_8cc_source.html

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-09**:
Thank you for your help. You already answered my question, but have you any thoughts, how to solve this 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "cartographer.mapping" ' problem?